# Durandaljs 2.0 overrides my css layout settings

Tags: durandal

Have a look at both images and you see that with durandal the layout does not work correctly.

I am using the Microsoft CSS grid layout for Internet Explorer 10+

I have upload a sample project here with Visual studio 2012:

http://speedy.sh/2QDQY/TLP2014.7z

In this project just go to Views\Home\Index file and outcomment the top 2 lines disabling durandaljs then the layout is fine.

Or enable these top 2 lines (outcomment the other html code in the index file) and the shell.html file is used then the layout is broken.

Is this my error or what do I wrong?

**Without Durandal**
[image]

**With Durandal**

[image]

Comment: Durandal is based on bootstrap, so if you use another CSS framework it's highly likely that there's some extra work to do. Pressing F12 and inspecting Styles|Trace Style should help you to reveal which CSS needs some extra tweaking.

Comment: Durandal uses bootstrap`s css classes in the html yes. But setting up my own views should not allow durandal to break my layout. A framework like durandal must be css class agnostic... I have used F12 in chrome and could not spot the bad boy...

Comment: I can understand you view point. Please report at https://github.com/bluespire/durandal/issues?state=open to ensure that your opinion is heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I  put a wrapper div around the header,content,footer and set it to height:100%; then its also ok with durandal. :)

```
#siteWrapper {
  height:100%;    
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 60px 1fr 60px; // header content footer
}
```

Was too late yesterday... the fix is also to make 100% height for the div with the applicationHost id! This is the root of... durandal ;-)

Comment: Good job. Looks more like a requirement of MS grid CSS and not a Durandal issue to me. Just as a heads up, you might need some more tweaking when working with Durandal's modal dialog as by default is has some dependencies on bootstrap.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit Thank you Rainer for the tip with the dialog which I will use too. Hopefully I can make it work and look good :-) I like bootstraps look but not the layout which I have to reinvent always with its stupid presettings...

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be MS grid layout interfering with Twitter Bootstrap. Have you tried commenting out the CSS includes for Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is not loaded at all. I have deleted it in the test project solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a fx_height.css to my site:

```
/*durandal fixes*/
#applicationHost, #applicationHost > div, #applicationHost > div > div
{
    height: 100%; 
}
```

My shell looks like this:

```
<div id="shell">
    <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
    <div id="wrap">
        <!-- ko compose: {
        model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <!-- ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 3 Sticky footer structure and its sticky-footer.css presentation.